# Creating an instance of an object in a for loop and plotting attributes on a matplotlib plot or subplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, instance

The data I have is  list of dataframes with the same columns supplied from files of interest input by the user. Dataframe columns and user inputs are passed into the __init__ parameters to create an instance. Some attributes of the instances are lists which I would like to plot when they are created in the loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats


class Sample():
    def __init__(self,initname,initlistA,initlistB,...):
    self.name = initname
    self.nums_a = initlistA

    '''There are more but are unnecessary to show'''

    def func(self,listA,scalar_A = 30 ,scalar_B = 10) :   
    x = stats.binned_statistic(self.nums,self.nums,statistic = 'count', bins = scalar_A, range[0,scalar_B]):
    self.right_bins = x[1][1:]
    self.y_values = x[0]

fig,axs = plt.subplots()


axs.set_xlabel('str')
axs.set_ylabel('str_2')
#axs.set_ylim(bottom = 0)
#axs.set_xlim(left = 0)

lst_of_dfs = []
files = []
while True:
    fname = input('file.xlsx')

    if fname =='Done' :break
    else:
        file=pd.read_excel(fname)
        lst_of_dfs.append(file)
    files.append(fname)


for x in range(0,len(lst_of_dfs)):
    name = files[x]
    df = lst_of_dfs[x]

    sample = Sample(input('name for {}'.format(name),df['initlistA'],....)
    sample.fun()



    axs.plot(self.right_bins,self.y_values,marker = 'x', label = self.name)

    print(self.y_values)
    print(self.right_bins)

axs.set_ylim(bottom = 0)
axs.set_xlim(left = 0)

plt.show()
```

self.right_bins and self.y_values return lists of equal length in my program. I am just not able to plot these lists on a plot or subplot.

Comment: Why can't you plot them? Is there an error that arises?

Comment: No error, an empty plot shows up.

Comment: Does `print(self.y_values)` print your list? Try `plt.gcf().show()` instead. gcf stands for Get Current Figure

Comment: I had left out axs.set_ylim() and axs.set_xlim(). Moving these after the loop solved my issue. I have updated the code to reflect the solution.